# Java MessageFormat resource with optional parameter?

Tags: java, optional-parameters, messageformat

Is it possible to have an optional parameter to a message format?  I have code that history for something with an event type and parameters encoded as strings.  This gets loaded by other code and does a resource lookup based on the type name (i.e. eventtype..format), and then passes the stored parameters.

One of the event types is 'action performed because user-defined rule matched'.  Previously, I didn't include the rule name as one of the parameters, and now I want to, so I was hoping to be able to use the same event type without redefining it just to add a parameter.

**My question is, is it possible to do something like this**

`eventtype.matchedRule.format=Action performed because of user-defined rule {if{0},(Rule name:{0})}`

so that if an event type of 'matchedRule' is loaded and has no parameters defined, this resolves to

`"Action performed because of user-defined rule"`

and if rule name was defined as "My Rule", it would be resolved to

`"Action performed because of user-defined rule (Rule name: My Rule)"`

Again, I don't really have control to pass a different resource at the time if there are no parameters, so I'd have to define a separate event type, which would be something like `matchedRuleWithRuleName` for new events that get stored, and leave the ones already stored with `matchedRule`.

Help?

Comment: I am interested in this as well. There does not seem to be any documented way to create boolean formats within the [MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) - have you found a solution by now?